# К чему в тексте относится "всякой на своё время года"?

Tags: согласование

> Помимо небольшого сада, у источника располагался ***свод приёмных покоев,
>   спален – всякой на своё время года (зимой на южной стороне, летом
>   на северной)***, библиотеки, кабинета хозяина – удалённых комнат дома,
>   на вилле располагались и термы (комплекс помещений для омовений, в
>   которых поддерживалась разная температура).

*"...Располагался свод приёмных покоев, спален – всякой на своё время года (зимой на южной стороне, летом на северной)"* - ***всякой*** относится и к приёмным покоям, и к спальням?

Если да, то какое окончание должно быть у прилагательного?

А если только к спальням - какое?

Comment: Думаю, что предложение надо редактировать, так как смысл расположения помещений совершенно неясен. И у слова "свод" какое значение? В словаре только свод законов или свод как перекрытие. Что имеется  в виду - соединение, последовательный ряд, галерея? Не очень понятный для читателя термин.

Comment: Жасминчик, а свода, увлёкшись всем остальным непонимабельным, я и не приметил... Спасибо!